# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.backendless.services.messaging.MessageStatus

Tags: java, android

getting a crash after sending message (it's a messaging app):

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.backendless.services.messaging.MessageStatus
                  at com.braunst.androidchatsdk.firebaseplugin.firebase.backendless.BBackendlessHandler$2.handleResponse(BBackendlessHandler.java:123)
                  at com.backendless.async.message.AsyncMessage$ResponseHandler.handle(AsyncMessage.java:64)
                  at com.backendless.async.message.AsyncMessage.handleCallback(AsyncMessage.java:41)
                  at com.backendless.core.AndroidCarrier$1.handleMessage(AndroidCarrier.java:37)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When clicking on the BBackendlessHandler.java takes to the following line ( Backendless.Messaging.publish(channel, data.toString(), publishOptions, deliveryOptions, new AsyncCallback())from the code below:

```
/**
```

* Created by Erk on 27.07.2016.
 */
public class
    BBackendlessHandler implements BPushHandler, BUploadHandler {

```
private static final String TAG = BBackendlessHandler.class.getSimpleName();
private static final boolean DEBUG = Debug.BBackendlessPushHandler;

private boolean isSubscribed;
private Context context;
private String channel;

public void setContext(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

public void initWithAppKey(String appKey, String secretKey, String versionKey)
{
    Backendless.initApp(context, appKey, secretKey, versionKey);
}

@Override
public boolean subscribeToPushChannel(final String channel) {
    if (!BNetworkManager.sharedManager().getNetworkAdapter().backendlessEnabled())
        return false;

    try {
        Backendless.Messaging.registerDevice(context.getString(com.braunst.amharicmessages.R.string.google_project_number), channel, new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(Void response) {
                if(DEBUG) Timber.v("Device has been subscribed to channel " + channel);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                if(DEBUG) Timber.v("Device subscription failed. " + fault.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean unsubscribeToPushChannel(String channel) {
    if (!BNetworkManager.sharedManager().getNetworkAdapter().backendlessEnabled())
        return false;

    // TODO: unsubscribe from push channel backendless
    // http://support.backendless.com/topic/push-notification-unregister-from-a-specific-channel
    DeviceRegistration devReg = null;

    try {
        devReg = Backendless.Messaging.getDeviceRegistration();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(devReg != null) {
        Backendless.Messaging.unregisterDevice();
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void pushToChannels(Collection<String> channels, JSONObject data) {
    // Configure the header
    PublishOptions publishOptions = new PublishOptions();
    try {
    publishOptions.putHeader("android-ticker-text", data.getString(BDefines.Keys.CONTENT));
    publishOptions.putHeader("android-content-title", "Message from " + data.getString(BDefines.Keys.MESSAGE_SENDER_NAME));
    publishOptions.putHeader("android-content-text", data.getString(BDefines.Keys.MESSAGE_PAYLOAD));
    publishOptions.setPublisherId(data.getString(BDefines.Keys.MESSAGE_SENDER_ENTITY_ID));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Only push to android devices
    DeliveryOptions deliveryOptions = new DeliveryOptions();
    deliveryOptions.setPushPolicy(PushPolicyEnum.ONLY);
    deliveryOptions.setPushBroadcast(PushBroadcastMask.ALL);

    // Publish a push notification to each channel
    for(final String channel : channels) {
        try {
            data.put(BDefines.Keys.Channel, channel);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Backendless.Messaging.publish(channel, data.toString(), publishOptions, deliveryOptions, new AsyncCallback<MessageStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(MessageStatus response) {
                if(DEBUG) Timber.v("Message published to chanllel:" + channel );
             }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                if (DEBUG) Timber.v("Publish failed, " + fault.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public Promise uploadFile(byte[] data, String name, String mimeType) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: HashMap != MessageStatus

Comment: should i add that in my code ? please explain a bit i get that HashMap can not be cast to MessageStatus/ How do i get to avoid the crash. Fairly  a beginner in programming.